Bivariate chebyshev polynomials
Chebyshev polynomials (of the first kind) are easily defined by
$$ T_n(\cos \theta) = \cos(n \theta) $$
Is there a piece of literature that tries to extend this to multiple variables? For example:
$$ T_{m,n}(\cos \theta, \cos \delta) = \cos(m \theta) \cos(n \delta) $$
My guess is that we would have either three kinds of polynomials here, saying one implementing $\sin(m \theta) \cos(n \delta)$, and one giving $\sin(n \delta)$.
In general, a $d$-variable Chebyshev set of polynomials would follow hyperspherical coordinates on $d+1$ dimensions. Have you ever seen something like this?

$\cos (m \theta) \cos (n \delta)$ is just equal to $T_n (\cos \theta) T_m(\cos \delta)$. And, say, $\cos (m \theta + n \delta)$ can just be computed using the angle addition formulas.

@QiaochuYuan yes that is obvious, but then what happens to the other kinds? A property I would like to get is $T^2 + (1 - x^2)U^2 = 1$, with three components
